# Flutter, Is initialization of Controllers with late modifier wrong?

Tags: flutter

In several code examples, the `ScrollController` or `TextEditingController`s are initialized in `initState` of `State<T>`.

How about `late` keyword initialization or just initialization with declaration?

```dart
class MyState extends State<MyWidget>{
  late final _scroller = ScrollController();
  // or just
  final _scroller = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scroller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }  
}
```

Is there any differences or problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference at all. The `late` keyword just means that the controllers will be initialized later with a value instead of right away.

As long as before you use the controllers they're initialized (either directly, or later), you're all good.